# My Ubuntu server shows tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968 when I try to run tmux. How can I fix it?

Tags: tmux

My VPS is NAT. It shows `tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968` when I try to run tmux command. How can I fix it?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @MichaelBay sorry. Edited it

Answer (score 8):

run this

```
apt install locales-all
```

Comment: Came here because I was trying to run `overmind start` (which uses `tmux` but does an internal check for `tmux -V` first) and getting the error `overmind: Can't find tmux. Did you forget to install it?`. Running the above fixed `tmux` which fixed `overmind`. Happy days!

Answer (score 5):

See Hitechcomputergeek's answer [Updated my arch linux server and now I get tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968 - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278401/89516).

> The same exact thing happened to me. Building on what Thomas said
>   above, I was able to fix it by uncommenting `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` in my
>   `/etc/locale.gen` file (previously none of the lines had been
>   uncommented), then running `locale-gen`.

Note: don't forget to `sudo locale-gen` and not just `locale-gen`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but Something I was trying to solve myself on `tinycore` kernel.
`tinycore` does not have locale-gen or other binaries to generate the UTF-8 locale files.
So I copied `/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8` from my local archlinux laptop to the `tinycore` (I had to create locale directory in `/usr/lib`) now the `tmux` is firing up with the UTF-8 I patched up.